# While writing pl sql query I am facing issue to get this result

Tags: plsql

I need to get active roll nos with their b_id if b_id_to_date>sysdate with b_categ value else b_id=null with b_categ aswell null

Table 1

```
column roll no,class,status
1       01       1      Active
2       02       2      Active
```

Table 2

```
column b_id ,roll num,b_id_to_date
1       A     01        dec-9999
2       B     01        dec-9999
3       C     01        Jan-2020
4       D     02        Feb-1990
```

Table 3

```
column b_id ,b_categ,to_date
1       A     Super  dec-9999
2       B     higher dec-9999
3       c     middle dec-9999
4       D     lower  dec-9999
```

Desired result :

```
tab1     tab1   tab1      tab2   tab2 
 01       1      Active   A      Super  
 01       1      Active   B      higher 
 02       2      Active   null   nulll
```

Comment: what have you attempted?

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name could you please help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood you completely but u dont need plsql for this task I got similar result with this query:

```
select t1.roll_no, t1.class ,t1.status, 
                              case  when t2.b_id_to_date <= sysdate then null
                                    when t2.b_id_to_date > sysdate then t2.b_id
                              end as b_id,
                              case  when t2.b_id_to_date <= sysdate then null
                                    when t2.b_id_to_date > sysdate then t3.b_categ
                              end as b_categ
from
table1 t1,table2 t2,table3 t3
where 
t1.roll_no=t2.roll_num and
t2.b_id = t3.b_id and
t1.status='Active';
```

Comment: if I do above I will get the below row in result which is not as per expectation  :
01       1      Active   C   middle
I need the result set exactly as I have  mentioned

Comment: no way u get that row bcs look at the querry  when: t2.b_id_to_date <= sysdate then null; the row in table2 where b_id is C that is below sysdate, it may be that the data in table is different than the data u posted.